# Giving all containers in a Kubernetes service access to the same shared file system

Tags: docker, kubernetes, samba, persistent-volumes

New to Docker/K8s. I need to be able to mount all the containers (across all pods) on my K8s cluster to a shared file system, so that they can all read from and write to files on this shared file system. The file system needs to be something residing inside of -- or at the very least accessible to -- all containers in the K8s cluster.

As far as I can tell, I have two options:

1. I'm guessing K8s offers some type of persistent, durable block/volume storage facility? Maybe PV or PVC?
2. Maybe launch a Dockerized Samba container and give my others containers access to it somehow?

Does K8s offer this type of shared file system capability or do I need to do something like a Dockerized Samba?

Comment: Especially in a Kubernetes context, it's very common to run multiple copies of each application component (Deployments running multiple Pods) spread across multiple hosts.  There are a lot of practical problems with using a shared filesystem in this environment, including file ownership, concurrency concerns, and issues arising from network problems.  How hard would it be to rearchitect your system to communicate over HTTP calls or a message queue like RabbitMQ, and remove the shared filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS is a common solution to provide you the file sharing facilities. [Here](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-volumes-example-nfs-persistent-volume.html)'s a good explanation with example to begin with. Samba can be used if your file server is Windows based.

Comment: Thanks @gohm'c (+1) I'll have a read. Is NFS similar to Ceph or GlusterFS at all? If not, what different problems do they solve?

Comment: In short, NFS focus is file sharing (like what you seek for above). GlusterFS focus is ability to scale the storage.

Answer (score 1):

You are right you can use the File system in the backend with Access Mode **ReadWriteMany**.

**ReadWirteMany** will allow the container to mount to a single PVC and write on it.

You can also use the NFS system as suggested by the gohm'c, for NFS you can set up the **GlusterFS** or **[MinIO](https://min.io/)** containers.

Read more about the Access mode **ReadWriteMany** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes